# Customized Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I am building my "base exception to end all base exceptions" class in C# and was looking for some opinions on my implementations so far. Ideally my usage of integrated Rethrow, Throw, and ThrowFatal methods for some syntactic sugar.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Schloss
{
    [Serializable]
    public class SchlossException : Exception
    {
        // member variables
        private bool _fatal = false;
        private bool _rethrown = false;
        private ArrayList _additionalInfo = new ArrayList();

        public bool Fatal { get { return _fatal; } }
        public bool Rethrown { get { return _rethrown; } }
        public ArrayList AdditionalInfo { get { return _additionalInfo; } }

        public SchlossException() { }
        public SchlossException(string message) : base(message) { }
        public SchlossException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
        protected SchlossException(
          System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
          System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
            : base(info, context) { }

        // rethrow an exception to preserve the call stack across threads
        public void Rethrow()
        {
            _rethrown = true;

            this.Throw();
        }

        // throw this sexception
        public void Throw()
        {
            throw this;
        }

        // throw with the fatal flag, in case anyone is listening o_O
        public void ThrowFatal()
        {
            _fatal = true;

            this.Throw();
        }

        // poopy, messy code
        public SchlossException(string Msg, params object[] AddInfLst)
            : base(Msg, SchlossException.GetInnerException(AddInfLst))
        {
            this.AppendAdditionalInfo(AddInfLst);
        }

        private static Exception GetInnerException(params object[] AddInfLst)
        {
            Exception Exc = null;
            if (AddInfLst.Length > 1)
            {
                Exc = (AddInfLst[0] as Exception);
            }
            return Exc;
        }

        public void AppendAdditionalInfo(params object[] AddInfLst)
        {
            if (AddInfLst == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < AddInfLst.Length; i++)
            {
                object Obj = AddInfLst[i];
                if (Obj is object[])
                {
                    this.AppendAdditionalInfo((object[])Obj);
                }
                else
                {
                    this._additionalInfo.Add(Obj);
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetAdditionalInfo(ArrayList AddInfLst)
        {
            string AddInfStr = "";
            foreach (object Obj in AddInfLst)
            {
                string InfStr;
                if (Obj is Exception)
                {
                    InfStr = (Obj as Exception).ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Obj is ArrayList)
                    {
                        InfStr = this.GetAdditionalInfo(AddInfLst);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        InfStr = Obj.ToString();
                    }
                }
                if (AddInfStr.Length > 0 && InfStr.Length > 0)
                {
                    AddInfStr += "\n";
                }
                AddInfStr += InfStr;
            }
            return AddInfStr;
        }

        public string GetMessageAndAdditionalInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                return this.GetBaseException().ToString() + " Additional Info: " + this.GetAdditionalInfo(this._additionalInfo);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    return this.GetBaseException().ToString();
                }
                catch
                {
                    return "No Exception.";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Part One - *Pink Glasses On*

**This as a qualifier**

I like how you're using `this` in the `Throw()` method. However `this` is used as a *qualifier* in `Rethrow()` and `ThrowFatal()`, and the usage or non-usage of `this` as a qualifier seems inconsistent, especially with private fields being prefixed with an underscore. Member method calls don't need to be qualified like this, `Throw();` is completely unambiguous all by itself.

**Comments**

I don't think any of the comments are useful. These ones deserves another look:

> ```
> // throw this sexception
>
> // poopy, messy code
> ```

Like I said I'd probably delete all comments anyway if I had to clean up that code, but these ones I'd delete twice. Call me a boring mug, I like professional code written professionally.

**ArrayList**

`ArrayList` is deprecated since .NET 2.0 blessed us with generics. Look into `List<T>` and `IEnumerbale<T>`!

**Naming**

Parameters should be `camelCase`;

> ```
> public SchlossException(string Msg, params object[] AddInfLst)
> ```

Should be:

```
public SchlossException(string msg, params object[] addInfLst)
```

Actually, `addInfLst` means nothing to me, and looking at `msg` I realize it's just disemvoweled and it has nothing to do with an *addIn*. `message` and `additionalInfo` would have been so much better.

---

#### Part Two - *Eyes Opened*

I think the premise is wrong:

> *I am building my "base exception to end all base exceptions" class*

A vast majority of all exceptions I throw are defined in the BCL. If you need to derive from your own exception classes all the time, and build a whole inheritance hierarchy of exception types... I'd say something's wrong: it's rather *exceptional* to throw an exception; throwing an *exceptional* one should be... *exceptionally exceptional*.

**Throw & Rethrow**

`Rethrow` should be `ReThrow`, but that's not the point: these two methods shouldn't exist at all. "Syntactic sugar", right. Every C# maintainer will expect an exception to be thrown/rethrown with the `throw` keyword. Calling an instance method on an exception type completely breaks the *Principle Of Least Surprise*, and makes me want to *go to definition* and see how it's implemented just to be sure it does what I'd expect it to be doing... and that's a sheer waste of time.

An exception doesn't throw or rethrow *itself*. With the `throw` keyword in the exception type, you're polluting the stack trace with useless information.

If I maintained code that uses this base class, I'd still be using the `throw` C# keyword, and wouldn't bother with these suspicious methods. Especially considering the actual syntax for correctly rethrowing an exception:

```
throw; // rethrows the same exception and keeps the same stack trace
```

Your `Rethrow` method actually sends the original stack trace to oblivion, and replaces it with one that's thrown.... *inside the base exception class??*

**ThrowFatal**

I'll be blunt, but *any* uncaught exception *is* fatal. You're twisting the semantics here, and I'm not sure I understand what this flag is supposed to be doing/meaning.

**InnerException**

From what I understand, you're using an `object[]` to store *stuff*, and in that *stuff* the index 0 might be an *inner exception*... but you're passing it as an actual *inner exception* through the base constructor.

You've just turned *simple* into *woah-wait-a-minute-here*. The inner exception is passed from your constructor, into the base constructor. That's it, that's all. It's not "additional info", it's an *inner exception* - it has nothing to do in that `object[]`.

**Additional Info**

The idea of "additional info" might fly... except it's weakly typed, and will box up all value types - you should avoid boxing value types into reference types, even for an exception class. In fact, I think it's downright wrong; the "additional info" belongs in the derived types, as strongly-typed fields and exposed with well-named getters - this whole "additional info" array smells like your base class is trying to do the job of its derived types.. at least to me.

Answer (score 12):

You're using `ArrayList` which is the weakly typed version of `List<T>`. Now, since apparently this is done because you're using `object[]`, I would suggest to just strongly type this to `List<object>` instead.

This is assuming your additional information is in fact different unrelated types and not always a `string`, for example.

---

You're explicitly naming the `System.Runtime.Serialization` namespace instead of using a `using` statement. I don't immediately see any naming collisions so I would omit this verbosity.

---

`this.Throw()` is more verbose than it should be: you don't have to make any distinction between `Throw()` methods so you might as well call `Throw()`.

---

Since `Throw()` only calls `throw this;`, I might be tempted to just omit the method altogether since you're adding another layer of complexity for really just two words.

---

Some comments should probably be rephrased in a professional environment as I'm sure you're aware.

---

Group constructors so they're all in once place.

---

Parameters are written in lowerCamelCase, so `Method(string Msg)` becomes `Method(string message)`.

---

Don't abbreviate words. `Msg` becomes `message`, `AddInfLst` becomes `additionalInfo`.

---

There's no point in saying something is a list if you can look at the type and see it's.. an array? That illustrates the problem with this perfectly: your variable's name does not take changes to its type in account. It doesn't add any information that I didn't know from the type; in fact it even added confusion.

---

```
private static Exception GetInnerException(params object[] AddInfLst)
{
    Exception Exc = null;
    if (AddInfLst.Length > 1)
    {
        Exc = (AddInfLst[0] as Exception);
    }
    return Exc;
}
```

This is a curious piece of code. Let me sum up my frowns:

- Should this even be in this class? Why not a utility class? If I needed to get the innerexception from an `object[]`, I'd look for something like `ExceptionHelpers` -- not `SchlossException.GetInnerException()`.
- Is the first entry always the `Exception`? Apparently not because you use `as` which indicates that it may not be. What is the expected behaviour when index `1` has the exception?
- No documentation that explains how this method would work.

---

```
if (AddInfLst == null)
{
    return;
}
```

You don't need this statement since passing no arguments to a `params` method will result in an empty array. Therefore it will evaluate the loop but never enter it, nor throw a `NullReferenceException` on `AddInfLst.Length`.

---

Local variables use lowerCamelCase so `Obj` becomes `obj`.

---

It is better to follow this idiom:

```
var x = y as z;
if(x != null)
{
    // use x
} else {
    // use y
}
```

rather than this:

```
if(y is z)
{
    var x = y as z;
} else {
    // use y
}
```

It's a matter of 2 casts vs 1.

---

Create an empty string using `string.Empty`, it makes the intent more clear than `""`.

---

When you're looping, use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings instead of `+=`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191079/does-stringbuilder-use-more-memory-than-string-concatenation

---